# Visual Studio Code - Path Intellisense - slash issue [HTML]

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Paths suggestions appear only when I enter "/", why? I want it to show when I type any letter.

Answer (score 0):

Because; this specifies an address. / then the text takes you to that page. 
For example ; banggood.in/login.html

Comment: OK but paths like this /images/image.png are wrong. I have to remove slash every time...

Comment: Because there are no other pages before the Images folder. İmages/image.png

Comment: Understand, but in brackets I don't have to type "/" and then to remove it so this is error I want to fix

Comment: I did not understand. Can you give an example

Comment: I need path like this: "images/image.png" but in VCS I have to type "/", suggestions appear, then I can choose folders and filles. So I have path like this: "/images/image.png" and this path is wrong. It works only without "/" at the beggining. I have to remove it every time..

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp. Look here. Path Browser search

Answer (score 0):

Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter.

```
ext install christian-kohler.path-intellisense
```